# iOS Significant Location Change Detection When Application Is Closed

Tags: ios, iphone, location, device

I've been trying to use significant location change while application is totally closed, but it's not giving desired results.

My application is supposed to detect when a trip is started by car. For this, I register for significant location changes tracking, so the application should be launched by iOS once a significant change takes place.

On simulator, I simulate a highway drive, and it works totally fine. However, on real devices, application gets launched after moving for 5 to 10 kms with very high speed.

I found on store other applications that succeed to perform that, so I'm wondering which part of my implementation is incorrect.

I've enabled location background mode at info plist. This is the code I use to start significant location updates:

```
self.significantLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.significantLocationManager.delegate = self;
if ([self.significantLocationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:)]) {
    self.significantLocationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;
}
[self.significantLocationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

EDIT: I've already requested and given my app permission to "Always" use location services. The application already uses location in foreground, background, and while terminated (but it takes it a LOT of time to launch from terminated state).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to ask Always permission to run your app in the background. The app will awake if the significant location is changed even if your app is killed. By that time you can not change any UI component (i.e. change label text etc.) Other than that your code is correct.